# Gradient of an Infinite-Dimensional Norm

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$, where $x=(x_1, x_2, \dots)^T$. Define,
\begin{equation}
  \|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kx_k^2},
\end{equation}
where $a_k$ are positive real numbers. How can I calculate the gradient of this norm? My approach is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
      \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\|x\| & = \frac{a_1x_1}{\|x\|}, \\
      \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\|x\| & = \frac{a_2x_2}{\|x\|},\\......
\end{split}
\end{equation}
How can I get $\nabla |x|?$ I mean, if my approach is correct then how can I write this in a vector form?

Comment: You may be aware, but note that in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, $\|\cdot\|$ is not well defined since something like $\|(1,1,...)^T\|$ may not exist depending on the choice of the $a$ coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You did all the heavy lifting. Taking your result on each partial derivative, you can conclude that
$$\nabla (\|x\|) = \frac 1 {\|x\|} \left (\begin{array}{c}
a_1x_1\\
a_2x_2\\
\vdots
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: You would need some $\vdots$ since this is in $ \mathbb{R}^\infty$.

Comment: LOL, I just noticed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write the coefficients $a_i$ in an infinite-dimensional matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty \times \infty}$ like this::

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots  \\
    0 & a_2 & 0 & \dots   \\
    0 & 0 & a_3 & \dots   \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Then we have $ ( \hspace{4pt}\cdot^{\top}$ denotes transpose $)$ :
$$
\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 = (A\mathbf{x})^{\top}\mathbf{x}
$$

$$
\nabla (\|\mathbf{x}\|) = \dfrac {A\mathbf{x}} {\|\mathbf{x}\|} 
$$